Flutter App Crashing in high resolution phone causing screen lock
I have a Flutter app installed on my Android phone. It works perfectly fine on phones with 1K resolution. However, the app crashes on phones with resolutions higher than 1K. When a user clicks on the app, the phone's screen locks. After unlocking the phone, the app starts working fine. Even if someone accidentally touches the app, it crashes and causes the phone screen to lock. If anyone has a solution, please share it.

Please [edit] your question to provide the stacktrace of the crash (from logcat) and also provide the code that causes it in the form of a [mre].

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
